# Adding matched string plus additional string after match in same line

Tags: bash, sed

I know the title sounds a little confusing, but hopefully my example will clarify my issue.

So I have a file with a list of names (names.txt), for example:

john

david

richard

I'm trying to use a loop to get to the following result:

john john.doe

david david.doe

richard richard.doe

Not sure if using sed is the right command or approach, but here's what I've tried:

```
for i in $(cat names.txt); do sed "s/$/ $i.doe/" names.txt; done
```

This 'sort of' works, but spits out an iterative list like this instead:

john john.doe

david john.doe

richard john.doe

john david.doe

david david.doe

richard david.doe

john richard.doe

david richard.doe

richard richard.doe

I've also tried a while IFS= read -r loop as well with similar results. Can't seem to just deal with each line without resulting above.

I'm likely completely off the mark here, but hoping someone can help here.

Apologies in advance. I've used sed before but for rather easier tasks.

Comment: General advice:  [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use `awk`. Command like this can do the work:

```
awk '{print $1,$1 ".doe"}' names.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Romeo. I was stuck on using sed that I completely neglected to explore awk. This worked beautifully!

Comment: Romeo, if someone puts `awk` in a `for` loop, would you rather recommend to use `sed` instead or explain what is wrong with that approach?

Comment: @Philippos, this depend of particular case. There no only one way to do the things.

Answer (score 1):

You midunderstand `sed`. You don't need to loop over `sed`, it loops over all lines anyhow. Simply do the replacement

```
sed 's/.*/& &.doe/' names.txt
```

`.*` matches the whole line, and `&` in the replacement inserts the whole match.

You don't need to switch the tool, just use the tool like it is meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

Done through sed

```
sed -r -e  "s/\s+//g" -e "s/.*/& &.doe/g" file1
```

output

```
john john.doe
david david.doe
richard richard.doe
```

Comment: Please mention that your code will work with GNU `sed` only. And while the first part is superfluous for a name file without spaces, an explanation what was wrong with the OP's original attempt would not have been superfluous.